# Laravel 5.2 authentication error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My 'users' table:

```
id,username,email,password,remember_token
```

Using default user model:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

I made only a simple update according to my DB, changing "name" to "username" in the model/controller and the register view.

The registration is *OK* and the user is authenticated after the redirection.

**The problem is in user authentication, I get this error: *These credentials do not match our records.***

The default login method (): App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@login

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    $throttles = $this->isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait();

    if ($throttles && $lockedOut = $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

    if (Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
        return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    if ($throttles && ! $lockedOut) {
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
    }

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:** simply I have updated the type of password to varchar(60).

If you have a custom users table, respect the default architecture!

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```